# Rails: Devise: How can I edit user information?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise-confirmable

I have a Rails app set up using Devise, with a Registration controller.

What's working so far:

New user registration
Login
Logout
Home
About
Confirmation
Password reset

Not working is edit, as in I can't figure out the URL/REST call I should be making to get edit to show up.
I do have a views/registrations/edit.html.erb page.

Following is the portion of my routes that's specific to Registration:

```
cancel_user_registration GET    /cancel(.:format)              registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /                              registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /request_invite(.:format)      registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /edit(.:format)                registrations#edit
```

Following is the portion of my routes.rb that's specific to devise:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => 'registrations', :confirmations => 'confirmations' }, :path => '', :path_names => { :sign_in => "login", :sign_up => "request_invite" }
```

I tried the following:

```
http://localhost:3000/edit  
http://localhost:3000/edit/:id
http://localhost:3000/registrations/:id/edit
http://localhost:3000/user/:id/edit
```

I get: No route matches [GET] ...

There are a couple of useful Q&A sessions on StackOverfloww, but I could not figure out how to make the advice here work for me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I typically just add a

```
resources :users, only: [:show, :edit, :update]
```

This will give you a /users/:id route (your profile), and can edit and update it. That way, you're interacting with the User model just as you normally would, outside of Devise.

Comment: I added this to routes.rb, and restarted the rails server. Now I'm getting the following error: uninitialized constant UsersController

Comment: You will need to implement UsersController

Comment: Wouldn't that conflict with my RegistrationsController? The registrations controller is handling new registrations.

Comment: No. And as I wrote in the routes, you're only doing the show/edit/update.

Comment: This seems to be working. I have some minor additional bugs. I moved show.html.erb, edit.html.erb and index.html.erb into views/users (as well as the corresponding methods from the RegistrationsController. The last thing I want to check after doing this is the destroy method (whether it belongs to the registrations controller or the users controller)

Comment: You can add it wherever you want, but I'd probably control it myself in the UsersController.