# How to permit a new param with devise for active storage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm on the latest version of devise 4.6.1, with rails 5.2. Whitelisting params in the application controller doesn't work for some reason. This code is taken directly from the documentation, I'm at a loss as to why this isn't working.

Application_controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 # protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  before_action :channel_variable

    def channel_variable
    @channels = Channel.all.order('created_at desc')
    end

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:avatar])

    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in, keys: [:avatar])

    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:avatar])
  end
end
```

Console:

```
Unpermitted parameter: :avatar
```

edit.html.erb:

```
      <%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
        <%= f.error_notification %>

          <div class="field">
            <div class="control">
              <%= f.label :avatar %>
              <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
            </div>
          </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found it best to create a separate route and `UsersController` to modify `User` attributes outside of authentication, including `Active Storage` attachments.  You'd want to create a `users#update` method and whitelist your `avatar` param there.  This is a bit dated but the accepted answer is the basically the approach you'd take:

[Rails: Devise: How can I edit user information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10900664/rails-devise-how-can-i-edit-user-information)

Comment: Any idea why my solution doesn't work? This is taken right out of their own documentation. Seems strange that you have to jury-rig strong params.